# UICollectionView/UITableView Universal App

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have iPhone app, which using UITableView with custom cells. I try to create universal app, and i understood that I need multiple columns for content. I thought that UICollectionView with custom cells will be the best idea, but I don't know how to combine UICollectionView and UITableView in one ViewController.

Maybe are there any possible variants to use different classes for iPad and iPhone?

Can anybody help me with it, or give any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`.

But you won't need both in same `viewcontroller` as I known.

As you said, To show multiple columns `UICollectionView` is good to go. `UICollectionView` does all things which is doing by `UITableView`. Even you can do much more things with `UICollectionView`.

You can simply even create your own layout. Or else there is a default `flow layout`.